# Adding two or more json to drop down in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

In Javascript, is it possible to add multiple json (json entirely,not some of their values alone) to a drop down?
Say, we have two json files like this:

```
var data = [
  {date: "A", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "B", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "C", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "D", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "E", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "F", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "G", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "H", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "I", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "J", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "K", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "L", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
  ];


var data1 = [
  {date: "m", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "n", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "o", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "p", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "q", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "r", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "s", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "t", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "u", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "v", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "w", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "x", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
  ];
```

Now,say we create two drop downs like the following:

```
<select onchange = "??" id="data" class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <option value="data">data</option>
    <option value="data1">data1</option>
</select>
<select onchange="??" id="total" class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <option value ="190">190</option>
    <option value ="90">90</option>
    <option value ="200">200</option>
    <option value ="100">100</option>
    <option value ="300">300</option>
</select>
```

What should be placed instead of "??" to make it work such that whenever either of the drop downs are touched, the filtered value from the selected json is printed to the console?

Comment: It would be a callback you wrote in Javascript that takes care of the logic behind selecting the appropriate data and showing it.

Comment: Yes, you need to write a function that rewrites data objects to html code.

Comment: Do you want to filter data for second `select(dropdown)` based on the value of first `select(dropdown)`.?

Comment: Yes.Say data is selected in first drop down and 90 in the other then all rows from data with total=90 should be printed.Next if I select data1 from the dropdown leaving the second drop down as it was,I should get the rows with total=90 from data1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9P8Qy/1/)***</kbd>

Iterating the selected json object and finding the necessity solves your problem

*Javascript*

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].total == total) {
        document.getElementById("json").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

us this code  http://jsfiddle.net/FeN7g/

```
$( "#total" ).change(function() {

    var selectedvalue=$("#total").val();
    $.each(data1,function(i,eacitem)
    {
        if(eacitem.total == selectedvalue)
        {
            console.log(eacitem);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the fiddle given below

```
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/Vt56E/1/